# Get result from prepared query in a MySQL Trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hello I am quite new to MySQL triggers. I want to get the result from a prepared query and cannot see how to get the following code working:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE un_quer varchar(255);
    DECLARE res integer;

    IF(NEW.contact_id IS NULL) THEN
        IF(NEW.name IS NULL OR NEW.email IS NULL) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Forbidden: ... information not sufficient.';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    IF(NEW.name IS NULL OR NEW.email IS NULL) THEN
        IF(NEW.contact_id IS NULL) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Forbidden: ... information not sufficient.';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    SET un_quer = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tender_tenderer WHERE tender_id=',NEW.tender_id);

    IF(NEW.contact_id IS NULL) THEN
        SET un_quer = CONCAT(un_quer,' AND contact_id IS NULL');
    ELSE
        SET un_quer = CONCAT(un_quer,' AND contact_id = ',NEW.contact_id);
    END IF;

    IF(NEW.name IS NULL) THEN
        SET un_quer = CONCAT(un_quer,' AND name IS NULL');
    ELSE
        SET un_quer = CONCAT(un_quer,' AND name = "',NEW.name,'"');
    END IF;

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM un_quer;

    SET res = (EXECUTE stmt1);


    IF (0 < res) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Forbidden: ...';
    END IF;
END
```

I think that most of the code works but the line "SET res = (EXECUTE stmt1); " produces an error. How can I select the result of stmt1 into the variable $res, so that I can use the resulting integer to be compared in the IF-clause?

NOTE: The basic problem is that I want to have a "unique constraint" in Mysql InnoDB which works with NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `SET` a query result to a variable, even if this query returns only one single value. Use [b.b3rn4rd's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21033134/1446005) syntax with [queries returning one single row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html). (fyi, the use of a [`CURSOR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html) is required for iterating over query results consisting in multiple rows)

However, a prepared statement is not required here, you can use the [null-safe comparison operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res
FROM tender_tenderer
WHERE tender_id = NEW.tender_id
AND contact_id <=> NEW.contact_id
AND name <=> NEW.name;

IF (0 < res) THEN
...
```

Comment: By the way, your first two `IF()` are strictly equivalent :o)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `INTO` statement.

```
SET un_quer = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res FROM tender_tenderer WHERE tender_id=',NEW.tender_id);
...
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, too, it is correct. However the answer of RandomSeed is how i actually solved it now.